# Is it possible to set user for jobs run on the cluster in spark standalone mode?

Tags: apache-spark

For example if a user submits a job, and the workers are running as some app acount, the jobs run as the app. Often it seems the cleanup step (removing tmp files) then tries to run locally as the user and you see errors. This isn't the only problem.

Is there some way of running as another other user in Standalone?